# External drive in constant use the moment a track from it is added to iTunes

Tags: usb, external-hard-drive, itunes, osx-mavericks

Adding tracks to my manually managed itunes library takes ages. I've noticed that the drive goes into a "constantly-in-use" mode (from the blinking led and spinning noise) the moment I drag a track from the drive into iTunes. From this point onwards, the drive remains in constant use even after quitting itunes.

Running `'sudo lsof | grep '/Volumes/<my-drive>'` doesn't output anything, but the bloody drive is still in use. And even though the drive seems to be in use, I am able to eject it in no time!

Here's my setup:

- Manually managed iTunes library.
- About 20,000 tracks already in the iTunes library. All mp3 files live in the same external usb 3.0, NTFS formatted, excluded from spotlight HDD.
  This is starting to make me regret switching to mac from windows :(

How can I find out what's keeping the drive busy?

UPDATE: I ran `fs_usage` and got this output https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmhVF.png

All these directories have already been added to iTunes, so why is it digging up more info about directories already added to the library?

Answer (score 0):

If you check the 'Keep iTunes Media folder organized' checkbox in preferences, then even if you haven't consolidated files or checked the 'Copy files in iTunes Media folder when adding to library' checkbox, adding new files to the manually managed library will no longer take ages.